# Add rel = "dofollow" to internal links

Tags: 7, routes, nodes

I wanted to add `rel = "dofollow"` to all internal links only like menu links, title links, user links etc. I managed to add `rel = "nofollow"` to comments and user posted contents. But I am not able to add `rel = "dofollow"` attribute to internal links.

Any suggestions how can I do this?

-- Thanks

Comment: AFAIK "dofollow" doesn't exists, and is the same as having no rel attribute, so there is no need to add it.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Can you give me some more information/link about nonexistent of dofollow. It would be much better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What some people call a "dofollow" link is just a normal link - i.e. a link that is *not* tagget with the `rel="nofollow"` attribute.

In other words, this what a dofollow internal link looks like:

```
<a href="target.html">target</a>
```

There is no `dofollow` (or similar) attribute you can add to the link.  The *absence* of `nofollow` is what you're looking for.